# Painting Ikea Stora Loft Bed

Tags: wood, furniture, repainting, primer, frame

My wife and I were able to get an [Ikea Stora Loft bed](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/80160867/) for my 2 year old son for free.  We thought it was a bunk bed and that it was dark brown, but it turns out its a bed on stilts and is black.  I like the size of the bed for him and the fact it has railings, so i told my wife I would try to make it work.

I need to do two things to get it to work:
1. Cut the legs to make the bed regular or lower than regular height.
2. Paint the bed an espresso brown

Cutting the legs wont be a problem, I dont think.  Just take off enough to have it sit at the height we want and put the pin in the bottom, even though it will be going on carpet

For painting, should I sand off the old paint first? It looks like its made out of pine. All websites say to use primer and just paint over it.  I have an orbital sander and its not a heavy coat of paint. Should I sand, prime and repaint?  Priming and painting over the original paint will save time, but I'd like it to last.

I plan on using a foam roller to paint, just need to know what primer/paint I need to get.

Comment: For Ikea furniture, I'd just get a few cans of brown spray paint + primer in one and go with that.

Answer (score 1):

Sanding is going to take a huge amount of time and for an IKEA bed I don't think it will be worth it. I think I would just paint it with white primer and then the colour you want.

Comment: Thank you for the help. All my research says to use  Zinsser BIN Shellac-Based Primer, but that is for laminate. Should I still use it for painted wood, even if I key the surface before primer?

Comment: To tell you the truth, I've stopped using all oil-based paints and finishes in the projects that I do. Oil-based paint takes so long to dry and smells so bad. The only advantage to oil-based paint is that its slightly more durable. Lately i have had good success with using a water-based clear finish (the kind you use on wood floors) over painted surfaces to add a layer of protection.